# Error when executing 2D dft using different row,col size with FFTW

Tags: c++, fft, fftw

I'm studying FFTW and My code was stopped on fftw_plan_dft_2d.
Here is my flow.

1. I flattened my 2d complex array into 1d fftw_complex array.
2. Hand over this array to 'FFT' which has fftw function.
3. It is run okay When I run this with **width : 10, height : 10**.

But I got error when I run this with different width and height like **width : 10, height : 12**.
When I run this, it just stopped with -1073740940 CODE.

So run again with debug mode, it stopped in below line
**forward = fftw_plan_dft_2d(width, height, fftData_in, fftData_out, FFTW_FORWARD, FFTW_ESTIMATE);**

I think my code has no problem and also c2c has no problem with different nx,ny size.
Could you guys help me with your knowledge?

```
#include "fftw3.h"
#include <math.h>
#include <complex>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h> 
using namespace std;

fftw_complex* FFT(double** data_Y, int t_height, int t_width)
{

    int i, j, height, width;
    height = t_height;
    width = t_width;

    fftw_complex *fftData_in;
    fftw_complex *fftData_out;
    fftData_in = (fftw_complex*)fftw_malloc(sizeof(fftw_complex) * height*width); // input buffer
    fftData_out = (fftw_complex*)fftw_malloc(sizeof(fftw_complex) * height*width); // output buffer

    for (i = 0; i < height; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < width; j++) {
            fftData_in[i*height + j][0] = data_Y[i][j];
            fftData_in[i*height + j][1] = 0;
            fftData_out[i*height + j][0] = 0;
            fftData_out[i*height + j][1] = 0;
        }
    }

    fftw_plan forward;
    forward = fftw_plan_dft_2d(width, height, fftData_in, fftData_out, FFTW_FORWARD, FFTW_ESTIMATE);
    
    fftw_execute(forward);

    fftw_destroy_plan(forward);
    fftw_free(fftData_in);
    return fftData_out;
}


int main() 
{
    int m_height = 10;
    int m_width = 5;

    double ** data_Y = new double*[m_height];
    for (int i = 0; i < m_height; i++) {
        data_Y[i] = new double[m_width];
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < m_height; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < m_width; j++) {
            data_Y[i][j] = j + 1;
        }
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < m_height; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < m_width; j++) {
            printf("[%f]",data_Y[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }

    //FFT   
    fftw_complex *fftData = FFT(data_Y, m_height, m_width);

    printf("============================REAL=======================\n");
    for (int i = 0; i < m_height; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < m_width; j++) {
            printf("[%.5f]", fftData[i*m_height + j][0]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    printf("============================IMAG===========================\n");

    for (int i = 0; i < m_height; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < m_width; j++) {
            printf("[%.5f]", fftData[i*m_height + j][1]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `fftData_in[i*height + j` should be `fftData_in[i*width + j` (ditto for the following 3 lines too). Not a problem with square matrices (height == width) but will cause problems with rectangular matrices.

Comment: @PaulR Thanks. But I want to use it on rectangular matrices. Is it possible? then what should I looking for?

Comment: Yes, that was the point I was making in the comment above - you got your array indexing wrong - if you fix that then it should work fine for non-square matrices.

Comment: @PaulR Sorry for my poor english understanding. It works fine now! Thank you so much.

Comment: No problem - glad to know it works now.